# flutter app api calls never returns in release mode

Tags: flutter, flutter-build, flutter-release

my flutter app works on debug mode getting data from api and all. but after I built the app in release mode and try to open it on my actual phone. It is not working getting the data from the api.

Things I have tried:

1. `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` and `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`  //added in AndroidManifest.xml
2. `flutter clean` and `flutter build apk --release` and `flutter build apk --split-per-abi --no-sound-null-safety`
3. added `shrinkResources` and `minifyEnabled` in android/app/build.gradle file.

   ```
   buildTypes {
   release {
    signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    shrinkResources false //here
    minifyEnabled false //here
   }
   ```

   }

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Try to run with flutter run --release and check if you getting any exception or not

Comment: Do you have firebase crashlytics in the app ???

Comment: nope. I don't use that. I am running it like you said, i will get back to you after it finishes

Comment: okay, can you share what is error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to find your error run it on direct release mode it can show what is cussing the error/crash

**Menu->Run->ReleaseMode**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

check your internet permission tag in android manifest.xml, just above the application tag.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```